# Python Discord Bot - Disable Commands Display

Tags: python, command, discord, bots, hide

I am trying to create a Discord Bot in python, and I'm stuck with making commands hidden.

Context : I want to create a bot with two commands with the same output, and when someone use one of them, I don't want other users to see which one was used.

To do it, I tried to delete instantly the command with ctx.message.delete(), but the message appear a few seconds, and a notification appears anyway.

Is there a solution to this, like a function that's applied before the message to be displayed on the server ?

Thank you in advance !
PS : sorry for my bad english...

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```py
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from random import choice
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

async def dispResult(ctx, res):
    author = str(ctx.message.author)
    if '#' in author:
        author = author[:author.index('#')]
    await ctx.send(author+" : "+res)

@bot.command(name='throw')
async def throw(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await dispResult(ctx, choice(["heads","tails"]))


@bot.command(name='fakethrow')
async def fakethrow(ctx, side):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await dispResult(ctx, side)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Edit : the goal here is to create commands like /me or /tts. When we use them, we don't see the commands itself, but only the result. Is there a way to achieve this, even in another way that creating a bot ?

Comment: This is just a Discord limitation. If you really want to hide the command, you could just have the user DM you.

Comment: To DM me ? The idea is to implement a command that nobody see, it's not only a message

Comment: It's not possible to make a command that no one can see. Discord is text-based, again if you want to hide a command from OTHER users, have the one calling the command DM you.

Comment: Discord has commands, like /giphy or /tts, and when you use it, you don't see the command itself, only the result... so why couldn't we create commands too ? Or is there another way to achieve this ?

And DM is out of the question I think, I want the result to be on a channel of the server, so it has nothing to do with DM.

Comment: And it's not that I don't want "other users than me" to see the message, I don't want anyone to see the command.
When I said "other users", it was to say that I don't want them to know which command I use, but in fact, it would be perfect to simply hide the command, as do /giphy and /tts ;)

Comment: well, /giphy is not send, because we click on a gif before sending the command.. but /me, or /nick, are exactly what I'm talking about.
More : /nick invoke a bot, so I guess it's possible, but idk...

Comment: It's simply not possible to add your own command like that.

Comment: You can't do that, wait until discord supports it.